# Colocar contraseña en asterisco y no punto html

Tags: php, html, css, html5, web

De tarea me han dejado implementar formularios con contraseñas ocultas por asterisco pero no hay info sobre este tema...

Apenas estamos utilizando html y css

```html
<input type="password" maxlength="15" placeholder="Contraseña">
```

Tengo esto por ahora ya le he aplicado en otras ocasiones id o name pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Creo que esto puede servirte. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186309/make-password-textbox-value-visible-after-each-character-input

Comment: Este link te va a ayudar bastante: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: Ninguno ha funcionado, necesito pasar de puntos a astericos, pero todos siguen en puntos

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que lleves, a partir de eso te ayudamos y evitamos el cierre de tu pregunta

Comment: <form action="" class="form-box animated fadeInUp">
        <h1 class="form-title">Ingreso</h1>
        <input type="text" maxlength="12" placeholder="Nombre" autofocus>
        <input type="password" maxlength="15" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <h5><button type="submit">Enviar</button></h5>
        <h5><button type="reset">Limpiar</button></h5>
    </form>

Comment: Necesito que se vea en asteriscos y no en puntos ya utilice, los name, los id pero eso tampoco me funciona

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código allí, no en los comentarios. Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para agregar lo que falta. Saludos

Comment: @BetaM el código siempre estuvo allí, solo que el usuario no lo supo formatear.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es posible solamente cambiando la fuente que usa el campo de contraseña.

```css
/* Use the css below to change the password input symbol */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url('https://mottie.github.io/input-password-bullet/font/fontello.eot?0000');
  src: url('https://mottie.github.io/input-password-bullet/font/fontello.eot?0000#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('https://mottie.github.io/input-password-bullet/font/fontello.woff2?13442593') format('woff2'), url('https://mottie.github.io/input-password-bullet/font/fontello.woff?0000') format('woff'), url('https://mottie.github.io/input-password-bullet/font/fontello.ttf?0000') format('truetype'), url('https://mottie.github.io/input-password-bullet/font/fontello.svg?0000#fontello') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

input[type="password"] {
  font-family: "fontello";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  speak: none;
  /* For safety - reset parent styles, that can break glyph codes*/
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  /* Font smoothing. That was taken from TWBS */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  /* Uncomment for 3D effect */
  /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3); */
  /* add spacing to better separate each image */
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" maxlength="15" placeholder="Contraseña">
```

Fuente: https://medium.com/@wowmotty/replace-the-input-password-bullet-1cd4ee34e0aa

Answer (score -1):

Prueba introduciendo:

```html
<input type="password" name="password" />
```

Comment: La consulta es cambiar el tipo de caracter de `input type password` de **puntos** a  **ateriscos**, para ocultar los caracteres escritos.